# asymptotically Stable solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ field such that $f(0)=0$ and $f´(0)=0$. Show that if $f$ is not increasing then $0$ is a asymptotically stable solution.

I don't know if I should find out a Lyapunov function or if it's possible to work only with the properties of $f$.

Waiting for suggestions, thanks.

Comment: You'll have to give more details. What do you mean precisely by '$f$ is not increasing'?

Comment: I mean that $f'(x)\leq 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What about the zero field $f(x) \equiv 0$? Does the inequality need to be strict, say $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, it is named in the hypotesis, $f'(0)=0$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true as stated. If $f$ is equal to $0$ in a neighborhood of $0$ (or just identically $0$), then the equilibrium at $0$ is not asymptotically stable. Nearby solutions do not converge to it, because they are all constant in time.

If you assume  that for some $\delta>0$ it holds that $xf(x)<0$ whenever $0<|x|<\delta$ , then $0$ is indeed asymptotically stable.